Looking for a formula to find a numerical value from a value ran in a table, bound by criteria, and return a qualifier from said table
From the picture below, I'm trying to get a return of either T1 T2 T3 (in Green) based on the Final value from the left table and its corresponding tier, from the right table and the tier criteria/range of values.
I've been trying with Index/Match but I can't figure out how to incorporate the range into the equation.


Please include what you've tried.

And here is another variant of the answer.
With the notation used, it is not clear to which category the border value is to be assigned. I assumed that it belonged to a higher category.
With this assumption, the following formula can be used (addresses as in the picture below):
    =LET(rw,INDEX($G$4:$L$11,MATCH(B4,$F$4:$F$11,0),0),
         res,XLOOKUP(C4,rw,$G$2:$L$2,"Below",-1,-1),
         IF(res=0,IF(C4=MAX(rw),"T3","Above"),res))



Based on my sample， you may try following formula:
=IFS(AND(K2>INDEX($A$3:$G$8,MATCH(J2,$A$3:$A$8,0),2),K2<=INDEX($A$3:$G$8,MATCH(J2,$A$3:$A$8,0),3)),"T1",AND(K2>INDEX($A$3:$G$8,MATCH(J2,$A$3:$A$8,0),4),K2<=INDEX($A$3:$G$8,MATCH(J2,$A$3:$A$8,0),5)),"T2",AND(K2>INDEX($A$3:$G$8,MATCH(J2,$A$3:$A$8,0),6),K2<=INDEX($A$3:$G$8,MATCH(J2,$A$3:$A$8,0),7)),"T3")


And another method, using LET for clarity:
D2:
=LET(
    d, Sheet2!$G$3:$M$10,
    rw, XMATCH(B2, INDEX(d, , 1)),
    bot, INDEX(d, rw, {2, 4, 6}),
    top, INDEX(d, rw, {3, 5, 7}),
    "T" & XMATCH(1, (C2 >= bot) * (C2 < top))
)

and fill down.
As did @McGonet, I made an assumption about the edge case which you can chang if that is not what you intend.

For older versions of Excel, you may try:
D2: ="T" & MATCH(1,(C2>=INDEX($H$3:$M$10,MATCH(B2,$G$3:$G$10,0),{1,3,5})) * (C2<INDEX($H$3:$M$10,MATCH(B2,$G$3:$G$10,0),{2,4,6})),0)

